# Xcode compiles swift code too slow because of it compiles twice

Tags: xcode, swift, compilation

I have an app, and it has extension.
So, all the files is extension are being shared with the app target.

The trouble is Xcode have to compile twice times with one file, one for the extension target, one for app target.

Any way to speed up ?

Answer (score 0):

the application extension doesn't share all the files by default. your application extension even though hosted by your application, has it owns live. if you don't really share some part of code between your application and application extension, don't add that code to both targets.

Comment: Yep, that's right, but i need to share the extension because i want to display it in the app. The question is how to compile once , not twice in this case

Comment: ??? "Yep, that's right, but I need to share the extension because I want to display it in the app" Is your application extension usable from other applications as well? Think about .... The app extension has nothing with your application. Yes, app extension is compiled separately as your application is.

Comment: The app extension is a keyboard, and i want to display this keyboard on the host app. What else can i do instead of share files to th host app?

Comment: After a user chooses a custom keyboard, it becomes the keyboard for every app the user opens. As you can see, it should not be dependent on your host application functionality. App Extension Programming Guide is good starting point to understand what apple means by the term application extension

Comment: Please focus on the question, you shouldn't question me why im doing my way. I've tried to call keyboard independently. But did you ever ask why Swiftkey is not doing that too? Me either Because i need to communicate and interfere to the every UIView, Control of the keyboard in the host app. So, please go back to the main question

Comment: if your file is targeted 10 times, Xcode will compile it 10 times (once for every target). App extension is the different target from your application target. If you would like to reuse the compiled code, put your share code in a framework and add the framework to all necessary targets. App Extension Programming Guide is good starting point to understand the whole process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116121/discussion-between-user3441734-and-tomsawyer).